# Getting state from URL string with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state, angular-ui

I'm using state-based routing (Angular UI Router v0.2.7) in a project and looking for a way to get the current state (name) from a given URL string.

Something like:

```
$state.get([urlString]) returns stateName:String or state:Object
```

I need this method to check if a state exists to a given URL because not all URLs are mapped to a state in my project. Using Play Framework as backend, some URLs (e.g., login form) are not mapped to a state because they using different templates then the Angular (main) part of my application. 
For those "none-Angular" pages (i.e., not covered by a state) I would do a reload. To identify URLs not covered by a state I need the method mentioned above. Planned to do it like this:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() { return $location.path(); }, function(newUrl, oldUrl) {
    if(newUrl !== oldUrl) {
        if (!$state.get(newUrl)) {
            $window.location.assign(newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Already checked the [docu](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) but there is no such method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the URL is outside the scope of the Angularjs project? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes, some URLs are handled by the backend (Play framework). Added some details above.

Comment: There is a `routes` file you can control who gets what routes. You can setup angularjs at the root of your URL `/` and redirect all the API calls to play from `/api`. Angularjs will never have to worry about it. Users shouldn't be given the API urls anyways

Answer (score 1):

It's all or nothing. If you plan to use ui-router make sure all your URLs resolve to a state.  If the state doesn't exist it will go to the `otherwise` state. It's possible to have optional parameters.

An alternative is to use `.htaccess` redirects to catch the URL and redirect you before it hits the ui-router.

Provide more details and we can see what the best option is.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Think otherwise could do the trick, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this will get the current sate name.

```
var stateName = $state.current.name;
```